# How to compare dates with Elixir and Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an instance of `Ecto.DateTime` that I get from a database column and I need to check if this date is more than 5 minutes in the past.

What is the best way to do that?

To make it more clear, this is what I need in ruby ->

```
updated_at < (Time.now - 5.minutes)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it using [datetime_add/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#datetime_add/3) using a negative value as the `count` argument:

```
from u in User,
  where: u.reset_password_sent_at > datetime_add(^Ecto.DateTime.utc, -5, "minute")
```

If you need to do it without using a query you can user the functions in the [:calendar](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html) erlang module:

```
ecto_5_mins_ago =
  Ecto.DateTime.utc
  |> Ecto.DateTime.to_erl
  |> :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds
  |> Kernel.-(60 * 5)
  |> :calendar.gregorian_seconds_to_datetime
  |> Ecto.DateTime.from_erl

Ecto.DateTime.compare(u.reset_password_token, ecto_5_mins_ago)
```

Comment: I am surprised there is not some convinient built-in function for this kind of things but thank you anyway

Comment: Not everyone considers the same things "convenient"